# How to fade an image into view from left to right using jquery?

Tags: jquery, animation

Would I use animate or fade or easing?  or a combination of the effects?

Comment: a png maybe?  That's the best way I can think of (irrespective of cross browser compatibility of course).

Answer (score 1):

you could try using Jquery's Slide effect which has a default direction of left as well as the fadeIn effect at the same time.

```
$(myElement).show("slide", 1000);
$(myElement).fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: Notice I do not chain these since chaining would make one happen after the other